# Can't get inputType='file' data on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, cakephp

In jQuery, when a function got success a form getting build. Now when I submit this form it gives all data except `inputType='file'`. I can't get it why this is happening

here is my jQuery code when form is creating

```
content += '<form method="POST" action="'+formURL+'" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
               '<input type="text" name="album_id" value="'+id+'">'+
               '<input type="text" name="user_id" value="'+user_id+'">'+
               '<input type="file" name="image" id="image_upload">'+
               '<input type="submit" value="Submit">'+
           '</form>';
```

Here form is getting submit

```
$("form#data").submit(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), formData, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

I am sending this form data in a controller in cakephp.
In controller I get only input field data with `text` type only. But I need `file` type too.

Comment: What you see if you try console.log(formData); before posting to controller ?

Comment: I think u need to pass just $this like this var formData = new FormData($(this)) or var formData = new FormData(this);;

Comment: I tried, but no progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use jquery.form.js for file upload.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

```
<form method="POST" action="'+formURL+'" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return submit_form();" >


function submit_form(){

    $('#data').ajaxSubmit({  
      method:'post',
      dataType:'json',    
      success: function(resp){

      }

    });
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Again, no success.  :(

Comment: i edit my answer please try this way.. i hope u will success.

Comment: Can i do this way? `<input type="file" name="image" id="image_upload" onchange="this.form.submit();">`

Comment: You can call the function onchange="submit_form();"

Comment: After getting success It's not updating images on page. when I refresh the page then it shows the uploaded image

Comment: refresh the div section by jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can change jquery function like this

```
$("form#data").submit(function(){

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
 });

  return false;
```

});